# VBA to save record and open a new record, but keep some text

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access 2007, I'm trying to create a macro for a userform. The form has trailer information and information about the contents. There will be many instances where I'll be entering data for the same trailer over and over, and I don't want to have to type in the trailer info every single time.

I'm thinking VBA will let me have a button that:

1. Saves the record to a table
2. Starts a new record but keeps some of the data in textboxes from the previous record.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your textbox name is 'txtFldA':

Add the following as a Form Variable (at top of all code)

```
Dim txtSaveMyData   As String
```

Then add a Form_Curent Event like follows:

```
    Private Sub Form_Current()
        If Me.NewRecord Then
            Me.txtFldA = txtSaveMyData
        End If
    End Sub
```

Finally, add a Before_Update event:

```
Private Sub txtFldA_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    txtSaveMyData = Me.txtFldA
End Sub
```